# Proverb for succeeding when in a comfort zone

Tags: пословицы

Is there a Russian proverb which could be used for saying that when at home, in a place one knows very well, or in a comfort zone, anyone is likely to win/achieve success? For example:

> Команда будет играть на домашнем стадионе. Что ж, у ребят хорошие шансы на победу. ... (the proverb).
>
> Ты только дома такой борзый. За границей - никогда. ... (the proverb).
>
> Ты так хорошо разбираешься в этом! - Да, нет. Просто ... (the proverb). Это же - моя сфера. Я этим занимаюсь всю жизнь.

Comment: I guess `Дома и стены помогают` (literally "Even walls help when you're at home") is exactly what you seek for.

Comment: @Fr0sT please, add answers that are providing something new compared to one that were already given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I actually can think of three, not one idiom that can be used (they are not interchangeable, each of them is applicable only for one of examples provided in the question):

> Команда  будет играть на своём стадионе. Что ж, у ребят хорошие шансы на победу - **дома, как говорится, и стены помогают**.

The next one is the quite odd and on of my Russian favorites (though I love dogs ))) - "собаку съесть [на
чём-то, в какой-либо теме] - literally [to eat a dog](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83_%D1%81%D1%8A%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

> Ты так хорошо разбираешься в этом! - Да, нет. Просто я **же на этом собаку съел**. Это же - моя сфера. Я этим занимаюсь всю жизнь.

Last one is less exact however very close:

> Ты только дома такой борзый. За границей - никогда. В общем, **смелый ты только, когда никто не видит**.